# Differentiating a bilinear form wrt x

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let f be a function from $R^4$ to $R$ such that $f(x)= x^TAx$ where A is a 4x4 real matrix.

The gradient of f at the point $x_0$ is

1. $2Ax_0$
2. $Ax_0 + A^Tx_0$
3. $2A^Tx_0$
4. $Ax_0$

How does one approach this? I tried to do brute force differentiation but I don't know how to differentiate it.

Comment: Compute $f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)$ and discard the quadratic terms.

Comment: Actually since we need to find the grad we need to take partial derivatives wrt each $x_i$ isn't it?

Comment: Not really, the gradient is (in this case) just the transpose of the (Frechet) derivative.

Comment: You can certainly do it using the individual partials but it is messier and hides the whole linear approximation thing.

Comment: If you follow my suggestion, one of the above choices will be obvious even if you do not compute the gradient.

Comment: okay I got $x^TAh+h^TAx+h^TAh$  ($x=x_0$)
The last term tends to zero as ||h|| tends to 0. Now how do I make this a function applied on h? How do I bring the $h^T$ to h?

Comment: If you are dealing with reals then $x^Ty = y^Tx$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So option 2 is correct? Please tell me

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$